# cors occured in React but not in Node.js why?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, axios

I'm using the axios with React and Node.js, but the result is different.

**With react, I got the CORS error but with node.js I got the response properly.**

The sample code is below;

With React

```
    import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
    import axios from 'axios';
    import hmacGenerator from '../utils/hmacGenerator';

    const REQUEST_METHOD = 'POST';
    const DOMAIN = 'https://api-gateway.exmple.com';
    const URL = '/deeplink'
    const ACCESS_KEY = 'xxxxxx';
    const SECRET_KEY = 'xxxxxx';

    const REQUEST = {
      coupangUrls: [
        'https://www.example.com/search?component=&q=good&channel=user'
      ]
    };

    const App = () => {
      useEffect(() => {
        (async () => {
          try {
            const authorization = hmacGenerator(
              REQUEST_METHOD,
              URL,
              SECRET_KEY,
              ACCESS_KEY
            );

            console.log(authorization);
            axios.defaults.baseURL = DOMAIN;
            const response = await axios.request({
              method: REQUEST_METHOD,
              url: URL,
              headers: { Authorization: authorization },
              data: REQUEST
            });

            console.log(response);
          } catch (err) {
            console.error(err.response);
          }
        })();
      }, []);

      return <div>App</div>;
    };

    export default App;
```

With Node.js

```
    const axios = require('axios');
    const { generateHmac } = require('./hmacGenerator');

    const REQUEST_METHOD = 'POST';
    const DOMAIN = 'https://api-gateway.exmple.com';
    const URL = '/deeplink'
    const ACCESS_KEY = 'xxxxxx';
    const SECRET_KEY = 'xxxxxx';

    const REQUEST = {
      coupangUrls: [
        'https://www.example.com/search?component=&q=good&channel=user'
      ]
    };


    (async () => {
      const authorization = generateHmac(
        REQUEST_METHOD,
        URL,
        SECRET_KEY,
        ACCESS_KEY
      );
      axios.defaults.baseURL = DOMAIN;

      console.log(authorization);

      try {
        const response = await axios.request({
          method: REQUEST_METHOD,
          url: URL,
          headers: { Authorization: authorization },
          data: REQUEST
        });
        console.log(response.data);
      } catch (err) {
        console.error(err.response.data);
      }
    })();
```

Why Node.js didn't get CORS error?

If you don't get my question, please leave a comment.

Please let me know.

Thanks.

Comment: are you using express in node as server side???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because React runs on the Client Side (Browser) and as Mozilla defines CORS

> Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) is a mechanism that uses additional HTTP headers to tell **browsers** to give a web application running at one origin, access to selected resources from a different origin.

Even if you use Postman to make this API call you won't get any **CORS** error.

Ref: [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS)

Hope it helps